# How do I setup i3wm on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, i3-wm

So I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10, and updated everything.
The issue is after installing the i3wm with the console command:

> sudo apt-get install i3

I can't use it. I log out, I click the little cog and all I have are 2 options:

> Ubuntu

and

> Ubuntu on Xorg

I can't choose the i3wm.
Are there any steps that I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

It seems you forgot "minus" (`-`) sign:

```
sudo apt-get install i3-wm
```

And install some tools to remove *"Error: status command not found or is missing a library dependency"*:

```
sudo apt-get install suckless-tools i3status
```

Then reboot and select i3 session on welcome screen.

Comment: Well for some reason everything seems to work after I restarted the PC, without typing in anything.
The most classic of all the clichés.